# Código para descargar un archivo excel ubicado en mi PC (localhost) con javascript

Tags: javascript

Me encuentro en la actualización de un proyecto web y requiero programar un botón que me permita realizar la descarga de un archivo excel ubicado en una ruta específica de mi PC, esto lo debo realizar con java script.
Espero su apoyo para sugerir como sería el código que debo utilizar, gracias!

Código:

Función Javascript:

```
function descarga(archivo) { 
    document.location = archivo; 
}
```

Llamado de función:

```
<a href="descarga(C:\Users\zzz\Desktop\Data\tc201803.xlsx)" download="reporte"> <img height="20" src="<bean:write name='labelsIdioma' property='btnDescargar'/>" width="92" border="0"/> </a>
```

Al presionar el botón, muestra para elegir dónde descargar, pero al aceptar, muestra

> "Error: ningún archivo encontrado"

.

Comment: Es muy ambigua tu pregunta, ¿el archivo se encuentra en el servidor o lo tienes en alguna otra carpeta fuera del servidor (localhost)?

Comment: Bienvenido. La pregunta parece una solicitud de código más que una preguntas sobre programación. Lo primero está fuera tema. Por favor sigue el [tour] y lee [ask] para que conozcas lo básico de cómo realizar preguntas en este sitio.

Comment: @ChristopherVilla, el archivo se encuentra en otra carpeta, fuera del servidor.

Comment: @Rubén, parece pero no lo es, ahora paso a explicarlo mejor:

Código:

function descarga(archivo) {
            document.location = archivo;
}

<A href="descarga(C:\Users\zzz\Desktop\Data\tc201803.xlsx)" download="reporte">
                                                    <IMG height="20" src="<bean:write name='labelsIdioma' property='btnDescargar'/>" width="92" border="0"/>
                                                </A>

Al presionar el botón, muestra para elegir dónde descargar, pero al aceptar, muestra "Error: ningún archivo encontrado".
Agradeceré su apoyo.

Comment: @Rafael39 Agrega el código a la pregunta así como cualquier dato que sea relevante.

Comment: No puedes descargar un archivo fuera de tu carpeta del servidor.

Comment: @Rubén, código agregado.

Comment: Como dice Dariel, no puedes acceder a la raíz de tu ordenador, todo debe estar dentro del ámbito del servidor. por ejemplo, todo dentro de las carpetas htdocs o www

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob, y en ese caso, ¿cómo sería el llamado?, porque también lo probé y sale el mismo mensaje, quizá y coloqué mal la ruta, esto fue lo que puse: href="descarga(img/Bines.gif), la carpeta img está dentro de la carpeta Web Pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tendrías que hacer es crear **directorios virtuales**.

> Un directorio virtual es un enlace a un directorio físico existente en
>   el disco duro del servidor.

Puedes crear un directorio virtual con el nombre "**Reportes**" que apunte a "C:\Users\zzz\Desktop\Data\".

- Apache: https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/1152.php
- IIS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb763173(v=vs.100).aspx

Si estás con otro tipo de servidor web deberías de buscar como hacerlo.

Un saludo.